# Regular Expression Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to check if an at character only exist in an android edit-view. I am new to regular expression and i implemented the forthcoming code.  where am i mistaken ? Here is my code

```
try {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/@");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valEmail);

        if (!matcher.matches()) {

            Toast.makeText(this," Invid no @ character ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: for which do you have write Regular Expression ,i think you want for Email?

Comment: i would like to check if only one @ character present in an email address using regular expression

Comment: if you want Regular Expression for Email check my answer.

Comment: You may want to look at [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/) for pattern for email validation. The problem with  your code is that you don't need the "/" before the "@"

Comment: Thank you for the site explanation. It helps a lot and you're right dude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your current code:

- The leading slash means it really is looking for "/@" rather than just "@". You seem to think that "/" does something special within a regex - it doesn't.
- You're using [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) which tries to match the *whole* of the input; you want [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) which will just try to find a match for the regex *somewhere* in the input.

Why are you using regular expressions at all though? Why not just:

```
if (!valEmail.contains("@")) {
    ...
}
```

That will check whether the address contains *any* "@" signs. If you want to check that there's only *one* "@" sign, you could use:

```
int atIndex = valEmail.indexOf('@');
if (atIndex == -1) {
    // Handling for *no* @ sign
}
if (valEmail.indexOf('@', atIndex + 1) != -1) {
    // Handling for multiple @ signs
}
```

If you *do* want to use regular expressions, there are rather more sophisticated email address validation regular expressions available. (There lots of different ones with different levels of validity - make sure you get one designed for the Java flavour of regex.) I wouldn't use one *just* for this though - only use regular expressions where you're really interested in pattern matching.

If you want to use a regex for "at least one non-@, following by @, followed by at least one non-@" you could use:

```
// TODO: Compile this once and reuse
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^@]+@[^@]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valEmail);

if (!matcher.matches()) {
    ...
}
```

As an aside, this:

```
catch(Exception ex){}
```

is *never* a good idea. Please don't just ignore errors indiscriminately.

Comment: Your code is very short, and very incorrect. Get it right first. I also wouldn't consider regexes to be a pinnacle of performance.

Comment: @user1355385: Compiling a regular expression and then using it is *not* going to be faster (or shorter) than `text.contains("@")`. And as StilesCrisis says - get your code *working* first before you worry about performance.

Answer (score 2):

For Email you can use Below Regular Expression .

```
 private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$";



    try {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valEmail);

    if (!matcher.matches()) {

        Toast.makeText(this," Invid no @ character ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a leading `/` in the regular expression that shouldn't be there.

Additionally, you should be using `find`, not `matches`.

Comment: this / intend to check if only one @ character present. Why should i remove it ?

Comment: @user1355385: Why do you think it will do that?

Answer (score 1):

`matches()` method checks if whole string matches to regular expression. You should use `find()` method instead of matches.And `/` character shouldn't be there.
But instead of all this you better use `contains()` method of string. `if(valEmail.contains("@"))`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@` without a `/` in the beginning.